# Access 'Chrome dev-tool mobile emulator' from custom extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to access 'Chrome dev-tool mobile emulator' from custom extension .

I am aware that I cant open dev-tool from custom extension.

Is there any way to trigger mobile emulator from the custom extension? If yes guidance/tutorials will do great help.

What I need -  I select a mobile device from my extension and browser will change viewport, user-agent, sensor to emulate selected device. In short I need replica of dev-tool mobile emulator.

Any help/link/code/extension link will do great favour.

Comment: Read through remote debugging protocol. Sounds like something: 1) currently impossible, 2) nice feature to request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `setDeviceMetricsOverride` via the devtools protocol. You access it at the `chrome.debugger` chrome extension API. You'll use that method and probably others to set the UA and such.

[Example code from my chrome extension](https://github.com/paulirish/emulation-popup-ext/blob/master/app/scripts/background.js).

[image]

Example (from [@onsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386509/onsy)):

```js
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Network.enable", {}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Network.setUserAgentOverride", {
    userAgent: deviceData.userAgent}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.enable", {}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride", {
    width: deviceData.width / deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    height: deviceData.height / deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    deviceScaleFactor: deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    emulateViewport: true,
    fitWindow: true,
    textAutosizing: true,
    fontScaleFactor: 1
  }, onResponse);
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example? `chrome.debugger` documentation is not the most verbose.

Comment: @Paul - Thank you for your time, Actually I have solved it long back, forgot to update the question

Comment: @Xan I have edited the answer with example, Waiting for Paul approval.

Comment: @onsy The edit will probably be rejected by the moderation queue; add your own answer, which does not demerit this one.

Comment: I've inlined @onsy's example. I've also added mine from a working chrome extension. https://github.com/paulirish/emulation-popup-ext/blob/master/app/scripts/background.js

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Network.enable", {}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Network.setUserAgentOverride", {
    userAgent: deviceData.userAgent}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.enable", {}, onResponse);

  chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride", {
    width: deviceData.width / deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    height: deviceData.height / deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    deviceScaleFactor: deviceData.deviceScaleFactor,
    emulateViewport: true,
    fitWindow: true,
    textAutosizing: true,
    fontScaleFactor: 1
  }, onResponse);
```

Comment: Added to my answer. Wikified my answer too.